# Parabola graph problem

Tags: quadratics

[image]
Find the  maximum vertical distance between parabola and the line 
Actual answer is 6.25
But why we can't just count it from graph but it give us 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I get:

If you denote the parabola $f_1(x)$ and the linear function $f_2(x)$ you can specify the distance between the two, at least in the area marked in the figure, as:

$y(x) = f_1(x) - f_2(x) = -2x^2+4x+3-x+2=-2x^2+3x+5$

Derivate to find at what value of $x$ the maximum distance occurs:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-4x+3=0 \Rightarrow x = \frac{3}{4}$

Insert into expression for distance again:

$y(\frac{3}{4}) = -2\frac{9}{16}+4\frac{3}{4}+3-\frac{3}{4}+2 = 6.125$

Answer (score 2):

Because the max distance is at the point when the tangent to the parabola is parallel to the line. The slope of the tangent line to parabola at $x_0$ is:
$$f'(x_0)=-4x_0+4=1 \Rightarrow x_0=\frac{3}{4}.$$
Hence the distance between the tangent and the line at $x_0$ is:
$$d=\left(-2\cdot \left(\frac34\right)^2+4\cdot\frac34+3\right)-\left(\frac34-2\right)=6.125.$$

Comment: If 5 is maximum value of parabola  how can it be possible to have 6.25?

Comment: The question is to find max vertical distance between parabola and the line. $5$ is irrelevant. Think of moving the green line up as fas as it touches the parabola. You can draw two lines to compare distances: $y=x+4$ and $y=x+\frac{43}{8}$. Actual answer must be $6.125$.